# How to update particular values in JSON

Tags: python, json

I'm trying to update particular key values that are in a specific block.

For example on the following String

```json
{"slot1":{"name":"","head":0,"face":0,"body":0,"neck":0,"hand":0,"feet":0,"color":0},"slot2":{"name":"","head":0,"face":0,"body":0,"neck":0,"hand":0,"feet":0,"color":0},"slot3":{"name":"","head":0,"face":0,"body":0,"neck":0,"hand":0,"feet":0,"color":0},"slot4":{"name":"","head":0,"face":0,"body":0,"neck":0,"hand":0,"feet":0,"color":0},"slot5":{"name":"","head":0,"face":0,"body":0,"neck":0,"hand":0,"feet":0,"color":0},"slot6":{"name":"","head":0,"face":0,"body":0,"neck":0,"hand":0,"feet":0,"color":0}}
```

I want it to update each key values based on what slot it's in so if it's `slot1` I want it to update that slot only. I basically  have a function that gets all the needed information from the client.

```py
    @handlers.handler(XTPacket('outfit', 'save'))
    @handlers.cooldown(1)
    async def handle_outfit_save(self, p, outfitName: str, slot_id: int, colour_id: int, head: int, face: int, neck: int, body: int, hand: int, feet: int):
        #self.outfits is where all the outfits are stored with the json string above
        #slot_id only returns a number 1-6 so I have to combine it with slot so something like "slot + slot_id"
 print ("Current Slot Name: " + outfitName)
        print ("Current Slot Saved: " + slot_id)
```

Comment: What have you tried, and what exactly is the problem with it?

Comment: There's no problem I just need mere guidance to be honest. Maybe a example to get me started.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just put `self[slot_id].prop` inside the function to update data based on `slot_id` value

```py
@handlers.handler(XTPacket('outfit', 'save'))
@handlers.cooldown(1)
async def handle_outfit_save(self, p, outfitName: str, slot_id: int, colour_id: int, head: int, face: int, neck: int, body: int, hand: int, feet: int):
  #self.outfits is where all the outfits are stored with the json string above
  #slot_id only returns a number 1-6 so I have to combine it with slot so something like "slot + slot_id"
  print ("Current Slot Name: " + outfitName)
  print ("Current Slot Saved: " + slot_id)
  self[slot_id].name = outfitName
  self[slot_id].head = head
  self[slot_id].face = face
  self[slot_id].body = body
  self[slot_id].neck = neck
  self[slot_id].hand = hand
  self[slot_id].feet = feet
  self[slot_id].color = colour_id
```

Comment: so if I wanna return the entire string with the updates I would just return `self.outfits` since thats where they were originally stored right?

Comment: I added a `Try` to get the errors and I got back `string indices must be integers, not 'str'`

Comment: `self.outfits['slot' + str(slot_id)].name = outfitName` change to string first

Comment: I just changed the argument to a `str` but it still shows that error and I changed it the way you mentioned as well.

Comment: What is output of `print(self)`?